# AngularJs file Upload using ngf-select

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular js and I have to implement file uploading functionality 
I am using ngf-select but it is not working. Below is my code snippet.

```
 <button type="file" accept=".txt" ngf-select="uploadFiles($file, $invalidFiles)" >
                                        <div style="margin-top: -8px;color: #fff;">
                                            <label for="file-upload">Select File</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </button>
```

Comment: Check upload module availability

Answer (score 0):

Check `ngFileUpload` injection in angular module and try avoid using inline css in html. It should work.

```
 var app = angular.module('plunker', [ 'ngFileUpload']); // ngFileUpload is required to include
```

Check plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/XCLYjn?p=preview